# Text is not getting on right side

Tags: html, css

Trying out hands on simple HTML. Want to put the sender address on the right side of the page but `<p style="text-align: right;">`fails.

I tried the solution form Mozilla MDN and other basic blogs on HTML and CSS, but failed to get a solution.

here is my code:

```css
body {
  height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 105mm;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Python Buddha" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Letter</title>
</head>


<p style="text-align: right;">
  <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
  Awesome Science faculty<br> University of Awesome<br> Bobtown, CA 9999<br> USA
  <br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
  <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
  <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
</p>

<h3>Miss Eileen Dover</h3>
4321 Cliff Top Edge<br> Dover, CTC XXX<br> UK
<br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: text-align: right is what you are looking for?

Comment: want to put send address on the right side of page!

Comment: just give a class to the p and add the clss to css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And there you go simple code:

```css
body {
  height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.sender {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Python Buddha" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Letter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sender">
    <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
    Awesome Science faculty<br> University of Awesome<br> Bobtown, CA 9999<br> USA
    <br>
    <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
    <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
    <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Miss Eileen Dover</h3>
    4321 Cliff Top Edge<br> Dover, CTC XXX<br> UK
    <br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want address in the right side, then there are couple of changes:

- Use div instead of p tag
- Then use float instead of text-align.

```css
body{
  height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

h3{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div + h3{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="author" content="Python Buddha"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Letter</title>
</head>

<div style="float: right;">
  <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
  Awesome Science faculty<br>
  University of Awesome<br>
  Bobtown, CA 9999<br>
  USA<br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
  <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
  <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
</div>

<h3>Miss Eileen Dover</h3>
4321 Cliff Top Edge<br>
Dover, CTC XXX<br>
UK<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about receiover address! it creates chaos onthe page. !

Comment: If you talk about horizontal scroll we can add width to control that.

Comment: how to render `Miss Eileen..`paragraph left aligned after (not on either side!) the receiver paragraph is the issue.

Comment: Okay now I got it. Just add this css "div + h3{clear:both}". You will get expected answer.Please check I also edited in the code.

Answer (score 1):

put `<p>` inside `div tag`

```css
body{
      height: 297mm;
      width: 210mm;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
}

h3{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p{
  margin-left: 105mm ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Python Buddha"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Letter</title>
  </head>

  <div style="text-align: right;">
  <p>
    <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
    Awesome Science faculty<br>
    University of Awesome<br>
    Bobtown, CA 9999<br>
    USA<br>
    <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
    <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
    <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
  </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Miss Eileen Dover</h3>
  4321 Cliff Top Edge<br>
  Dover, CTC XXX<br>
  UK<br>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of `p`.

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
  Awesome Science faculty<br> University of Awesome<br> Bobtown, CA 9999<br> USA
  <br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
  <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
  <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
</div>
```

Or if you want to show one is in right side and another part in left side. Then you can do this.

```html
<div style="float: right;">
  <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
  Awesome Science faculty<br> University of Awesome<br> Bobtown, CA 9999<br> USA
  <br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
  <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
  <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but still not rendered the text the way it should look!

Comment: How you want to make it look. Can you explain ?

Comment: all the text should start from same column. with `div`it gets bit unordered and space at beginning of each line makes the text not beautiful.

Comment: If it is works then please accept the answer so that other can get the working answer while anyone facing same issue

Comment: @PythonBuddha appreciate your `thanks, it worked`, but this is stackoverflow, make it flow, accept the answer mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

you should store it on div tag.

```
 <div style="text-align: right">
   <h2>text-align: right:</h2>
 </div>
```

so it will be like this..

```html
<div style="text-align: left; float: right;">
  <h3>Dr. Eleanor Gaye</h3>
  Awesome Science faculty<br> University of Awesome<br> Bobtown, CA 9999<br> USA
  <br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-4567890<br>
  <strong>E-mail</strong>:no_reply@example.com<br>
  <time datetime="">20 January 2016</time>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but it provokes another paragraph `receiver` to come left side of it. So, `div` with appropriate `class_name` is good solution.